# use WebDriverWait by class name when there are more class with the same name

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I use this code in normal way:

```
driver.find_elements_by_class_name('-nl3')[1]
```

But when I want to wait until element display by 'WebDriverWait' I don't now where I must write index:

```
WebDriverWait(driver,delay).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.CLASS_NAME, '-nl3')))
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can use lambda function in it. like this:

```
WebDriverWait(driver,delay).until(lambda d: driver.find_elements_by_class_name('-nl3')[1])
```